# PHP echo plain text

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk and using php on it.

But when I try to echo some html / javascript text, it just get print me plain text !

Here's an example :

```
<?php 
  public function testing (){
       echo "<h1>Hello World !</h1>";
  }
?>
```

Gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Du3o.png).

For information I am working with an api, and my *testing* function is called on http://xxx.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/test/lavachart

I really can't understand why the html / javascript code isn't interpreted.

Thanks for answers

Comment: Probably correct http headers are missing for `Content-Type: text/html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
  header('Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  public function testing (){
       echo "<h1>Hello World !</h1>";
  }
?>
```

for example you need response right content type for your php script, if this html then content type text/html. But you can have not right configuration server.
you can just adding mime for php in you .htaccess file or virtualhost configuration

```
AddType text/html .php
```